# AWS - Cannot access RedShift endpoint from the SageMaker Studio

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-sagemaker

## Question

Please advise how to trouble shoot the problem.

## Problem

Cannot access the RedShift cluster endpoint from the SageMaker studio instance.

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
result = sock.connect_ex(('dsoaws.cw7xniw3gvef.us-east-2.redshift.amazonaws.com',5439))
if result == 0:
   print("Port is open")
else:
   print("Port is not open")
sock.close()
---

Port is not open
```

## RedShift Cluster

Endpoint is `dsoaws.cw7xniw3gvef.us-east-2.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/dsoaws`.

[image]

The network setting shows the VPC is vpc-5b123432 allowing access from sg-56cb133e.

[image]

---

## SageMaker Studio

The SageMaker Studio instance is in the save VPC vpc-5b123432. However, not sure if sg-56cb133e is actually attached to the SageMaker studio instance. Please advise how to confirm if the sg-56cb133e is attached to the instance.

```
import json
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
from botocore.config import Config

config = Config(
   retries = {
      'max_attempts': 10,
      'mode': 'adaptive'
   }
)


iam = boto3.client('iam', config=config)
sts = boto3.client('sts')
redshift = boto3.client('redshift')
sm = boto3.client('sagemaker')
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')

try:
    domain_id = sm.list_domains()['Domains'][0]['DomainId'] #['NotebookInstances'][0]['NotebookInstanceName']
    describe_domain_response = sm.describe_domain(DomainId=domain_id)
    vpc_id = describe_domain_response['VpcId']
    print(vpc_id)
    security_groups = ec2.describe_security_groups()['SecurityGroups']
    for security_group in security_groups:
        if vpc_id == security_group['VpcId']:
            security_group_id = security_group['GroupId']
    print(security_group_id)
except:
    pass
-----
vpc-5b123432
sg-56cb133e
```

---

## Security Group

[image]

[image]

## IAM

The IAM role `SageMaker` is attached to the SageMaker Studio.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Cause

Did not use VPC Only sagemaker deployment as having used the Quick Start onboard.

## Fix

1. Deleted the SageMaker Studio. R
2. Recreated by using the Standard Setup + VPC only
   [image]
3. Added the NAT and configured the routing tables.

## References

- [Securing Amazon SageMaker Studio connectivity using a private VPC](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/securing-amazon-sagemaker-studio-connectivity-using-a-private-vpc/)
- [Amazon SageMaker Studio in a private VPC with NAT Gateway and Network Firewall](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-studio-vpc-networkfirewall)

Comment: Why is VPC Only required?